# Get the database backup using PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli, backup

following is the code I found over the internet to get the database backup using php. code works fine in the local host. but when it is in the online server, it does not works properly. it creates a database .sql file but the file is empty. what is the problem?? I think it is a server permission problem. how can I make this code works on my online server.??? :(

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dhn_online_db");

$tables = array();
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW TABLES');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
     $tables[] = $row[0];
}

$result = "";
foreach($tables as $table){
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($query);

$result .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
$result .= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
   $result .= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
     for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++){
       $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
       $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
       if(isset($row[$j])){
           $result .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; 
        }else{ 
            $result .= '""';
        }
        if($j<($num_fields-1)){ 
            $result .= ',';
        }
    }
    $result .= ");\n";
}
}
$result .="\n\n";
}

//Create Folder
$folder = 'Backup_Files/';
if (!is_dir($folder))
mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
chmod($folder, 0777);

$date = date('m-d-Y'); 
$filename = $folder."db_backup_".$date; 
echo $filename;
$handle = fopen($filename.'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$result,0777);
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: You are missing `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script. Add the code I mentioned and see if any specific lines are producing errors.

Comment: I wonder why do you want to implement `mysqldump` in PHP. The whole thing is done with a single command like `mysqldump db > backup$(date +%F_%T).sql`

Comment: There are Export functions in PHPMyAdmin, if it is available to you.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov please tell me how to do it. like what is the exact code to get the backup.

Comment: @ChinthakaUdayasiri, for your example the command will look like `mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot dhn_online_db > ~/Backup_Files/db_backup_$(date +%m-%d-%Y).sql` (note, password can be specified with `-p` option). Put this command in `crontab` (a running cron daemon required) like `@daily this-command`. And you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel ?

```
$folder = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Backup_Files/';
if (!is_dir($folder)){
    mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
    $date = date('m-d-Y'); 
    exec("mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME > {$folder}db_backup_{$date}.sql");
}
```

Comment: He doesn't even need PHP

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov agreed, but I guess the OP wants to use php for whatever reason he/she has.

Comment: i need this function to create a backup file when a user logout from the system.